# Bootstrap - alert-error doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing a web-script to handle VPS Creation and Destruction. On the admin page, I use Twitter Bootstrap to show an alert for success and failure messages. Here lies the problem, the `.alert-success` div works, but the `.alert-error` doesn't. I have most of my code (minus the PHP script), posted on a **Pastebin** [**here**](http://pastebin.com/WkwjKD1a).

I have some screenshots on how it looks for me on Internet Explorer 11 [here](http://i62.tinypic.com/4kchnb.png).

[image]

Please note that the alert-success area works. I use a Custom Bootstrap to change the font, but that's it. I created it using the getbootstrap.com website, so I doubt it's that.

Comment: hi...welcome to community...can u paste what is being rendered by PHP on browser upon error?? :)

Comment: `alert-error` doesn't exist in Bootstrap 3, it should be `alert-danger` If you're using the latest version of Bootstrap that is..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

they have changed alert-error to alert-danger.
And please access jquery before bootstrap as Felix has said..
this ran fine on my pc:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Theme Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="Assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="Assets/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
                HR {
                        page-break-before: always;
                        padding-bottom: 10px;
                }
        </style>
    <!-- Bootstrap theme -->
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
     <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
   <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body role="document">

    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">VZControlPanel</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
            <li><a href="login.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">

      <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Admin Summary</h1>
        <p>NODE STATUS: 1 nodes online.</p>
      </div>

        <?php
        $success=0;
          if($success===1) {
      echo '<div class="alert alert-success">';
       echo '<strong>SUCCESS:</strong> Action completed successfully!';
           echo '<a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>';
       echo '</div>';
          } else if($success===0) {
           echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">';
       echo "<strong>FAILED:</strong> Action didn't complete successfully!";
           echo '<a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>';
       echo '</div>';

          }
    ?>
    <hr>
                <h2>Create VM</h2>
                <form action="admin.php" method="get">
                        <input name="action" value="create" type="hidden">
                        VMID: <input name="id" type="text"><br>
                        IP: <input name="ip" type="text"><br>
                        OS Template: <input name="os" type="text"><br>
                        NodeID: <input name="nid" type="text"><br>
                        Assign To: <input name="user" type="text"><br>
                        <input name="submit" value="Create VM" type="submit">
                </form>
        <hr>
                <h2>Destroy VM</h2>
                <form action="admin.php" method="get">
                        <input name="action" value="destroy" type="hidden">
                        VMID: <input name="id" type="text"><br>
                        NodeID: <input name="nid" type="number" maxlength="3"><br>
                        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Destroy VM">
                </form>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
   ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didn't realize they changed that API.

Comment: No harm. I too was going through the same mistake.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like you are using Bootstrap 3. They've changed the class name from alert-error to alert-danger.

So,what you probably want is class `alert-danger` and *not* `alert-error` ( *its with version 2.x* ).

Answer (score 1):

Based on your `pastebin` you need to reverse the order of your included scripts, you need to include jQuery first then Bootstrap since Bootstrap require jQuery to works, so you can change:

```
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Reversed order doesn't seem to fix anything. No change in the output.